# Please synonym 'opening' and 'openings'

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms, retagging

I think we need to make [opening](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opening) a synonym for [openings](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openings).

Plural seems the better way to go, and we don't need these two separate tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've submitted [opening](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opening) as synonym for [openings](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openings).

Comment: Thanks, I'm just one upvote away from being able to vote on it.

Comment: Well, I have the votes now, but it looks like one of you guys pushed it through, thanks.

Comment: @Lance - yeah, it wasn't immediately obvious how to approve it, but I stumbled my way through :)

Comment: While it shows as a tag-synonym on the openings page.  If you try to add it to a question, it doesn't have the (s), and it didn't migrate the tags over, so there are still 11 questions with 'opening'.

Comment: ok I tried to take care of them all.  Since you can't search for a synonymed tag, I can't be sure.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Its over 3 years since this issue was raised, questions can still have one or both of the tags. Please see if more attention needs to be raised.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code, no, it did get synonymed.  Notice that when you search for either you end up with the same number of questions.  I found no questions with both tags.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Then why do I still get an option to use both tags on a new question?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code, there does appear to be a bug, see my larger [meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248113/tag-synonym-somewhat-acting-like-real-tag) that I've just posted.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code, ok, got the answer and fixed it.